# Using equal values within 2 arrays to display values from third array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that i want to compare, and then collect the similar values to use in order to display values from a third array.
array 1:

```
$Global_Days = array("Monday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday");
```

array 2:

```
$Global_Day = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
```

array 3:

```
$Global_Dates = array("11-05-2015", "12-05-2015", "13-05-2015", "14-05-2015", "15-05-2015", "16-05-2015", "17-05-2015");
```

So what i basically want is for it to display the date equal to the days shown in the first array, so this example would show:

```
11-05-2015
14-05-2015
15-05-2015
17-05-2015
```

From what I have seen, array_intersect() is roughly what I am looking for, but examples that I have seen of it are very confusing.
the data shown here is a bit different to what I intend to use, but this functionality is what I need, so giving alternatives to getting the date won't help

Comment: Use `array_intersect` on the first two arrays. Then loop through `array3`, get the day name from the date, and use `in_array()` to see if it's in the intersection.

Comment: What do you find confusing about `array_intersect`? It just returns a new array that has all the elements in common from the input arrays.

Comment: There isn't very much documentation that discusses array_intersect, particularly about the ordering of the arrays that you should give it. Finally got the array intersect working, just trying to manage the data now

Comment: The ordering doesn't matter.

Comment: isn't very much documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Comment: @Sean, manuals are for amateurs :P

Comment: @Devon,  the comments section in the manuals is for amateurs ;)

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I build my code from only the comments section.

Comment: (i've been cynical, there is gold in some of those comments and sometimes they're involve lot of thinking and investigating)

Comment: @Devon reminds me of my friend who took 3 hrs to install a ceiling fan, and then his frustrated wife finally told him to open the #@$% instructions that came with it

Comment: @Sean, my wobbly table from IKEA works just fine without the manual.

Comment: @OfirBaruch, I was being sarcastic :) hard to tell over comments sometimes.

Comment: @Devon you could fold up the manual and use it to stabilize the short leg on the table.

Answer (score 1):

Things to note. When intersecting you need to pay attention to your first array, the one to be compared against. array_intersect provides you all of the values in $Global_Day at the indices mapped to $Global_Dates. You can then map the result of this intersection with with $Global_Dates to retrieve the mapped values by comparing the keys retrieved from the first intersection.

This should achieve your goal

```
$Global_Days = array("Monday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Sunday");
$Global_Day = array("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday");
$Global_Dates = array("11-05-2015", "12-05-2015", "13-05-2015", "14-05-2015", "15-05-2015", "16-05-2015", "17-05-2015");

$keys = array_intersect($Global_Day, $Global_Days);
$result = array_intersect_key($Global_Dates, $keys);
```

Try it out: http://www.tehplayground.com/#zkyzV0dwH

Comment: Tried this code, it seems to print out the first 4 values of $Global_Dates as opposed to the dates designated through the array. Its fine though, i've got what i needed :)

Comment: How does `array_intersect_key` find the dates that are on the specified days of the week?

Comment: It should work just fine. @Barmar, the result of array_intersect, when you use Global_Day as your first array returns an intersection mapped to the same indices (which are the keys in the map) as in Global_Day but only of the values in Global_Days. Then array_intersect_key only returns the values mapped to those specific indices since they are the keys that the previous intersection contains.

Comment: I didn't realize that `$Global_Dates` corresponds directly with `$Global_Day`. I thought it was a random collection of dates, and we needed to get the day of week from each of them to compare.

Comment: @Barmar yea it does, wouldn't work in my php though, maybe i've named something wrong in the document. Either way, `array_intersect_key` looks quite useful, will remember it for later coding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, heres what i ended up using, might not be optimal, but it gets the values, tried to code based on Barmars answer and ended up with this:

```
$ans = array_intersect($Global_Days, $Global_Day);
$AKans = array_keys($ans); 
for ($z=0; $z < count($AKans); $z++ ){
$TAK = $AKans[$z];
echo $Global_Dates[$TAK];
echo "</br>";
}
```